# No match for argument: pyhton3-argcomplete

Tags: python, centos

I tried to install pyhton3-argcomplete on my centos machine.
I run yum command and get below error message ;

```
sudo yum install -y pyhton3-argcomplete
No match for argument: pyhton3-argcomplete
```

anyone have same issue?
Checked my available repositories to see if the package is available :

> yum search *argcomplete*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo in the package name, instead of `pyhton3` it should be `python3`.
Try this:

```
sudo yum install -y python3-argcomplete
```